# How might inducted current/ voltage in multiple coil layers connected in parallel behave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, induction

This is a branch from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110087/what-are-the-variables-at-play-during-magnetic-induction).

- In the event that two or more layers are connected in parallel - would the energy created across each layer likely be significantly less? In the event of (say) five layers of coiling connecting, each with differing currents (or voltages), how might the resultant current be combined once reunited (presuming a similar wire is receiving the energy)?

Would the variances result in feedback from the coils with most induced energy into the coils with least induced energy (at the point of uniting)?

Are there further aspects that you would consider?